Considering Le Chatelier's principle, what happens when you add more solute to a saturated solution already in equilibrium?
If I'm not wrong saturated solutions are in dynamic equilibrium. Will the addition of solute disturb the equilibrium? What exactly occurs and how to apply Le Chatelier's principle?

To be saturated some solid must also be present in contact with the solution. Adding more solid will not make the solution more saturated or less saturated.

Quantitatively, increasing concentration of dissolved solutes, or increasing partial pressure of gases, increases their chemical potential $\mu_i=\left(\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial n_i}\right)_{p,T,n_j,j \ne i}$ what shifts the equilibrium.
Increasing amount of pure undissolved solid or liquid does not change its chemical potential and therefore does not shift the equilibrium.
If chemical potential of some component is externally increased, the Le Chatelier's principle works on its decreasing.
